# auto install script: ffmpeg + most supported codecs

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I would like to install the real ffmpeg framework on my Mint 16 (not the libav one!).

The problems are:

- The public available ffmpeg install packages only offer versions of ffmpeg that do not support non-free codecs.
- I am not able to compile my own ffmpeg package with most codecs enabled, because I have trouble to compile some of the external libraries that are needed to compile ffmpeg.

So I'm asking here, if somebody knows an install script that does compile ffmpeg with almost all codecs enabled (I would not mind paying for this script, if it actually works).

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

P.S.
I already found such an offer https://admin-ahead.com/script-solutions-a-aast-ffmpeg-installer/.
The problem is: They only give out licenses to one ip-address.
So, when I would use it, the license will apply to my current IP-address and when my ISP changes my IP, I would not be able to use my license anymore.
This install script is obviously only intended for people owning a server

Comment: What are the specific audio codecs you need? Understand that the best (to some also the easiest) way to proceed is to compile the libraries. Also note that if you **don't need** the libraries, it's best you leave them out. It's only too easy to fall into a "bloatware" trap. Unless you experiment or test stuff- you should stick to what you really need. Also, ffmpeg is free. Most people here are trying to keep that spirit of freedom up- by providing time and effort for free. It's likely that you wouldn't need to pay for any script or anything else on the front of ffmpeg.

Comment: Did you see [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide)? Was there something wrong with this guide?